# Best method for spline with lots of faces

Tags: three.js

Let's say I have a spline that is 20,000ft long. So I set the segments to 20,000. I also need 36 faces around each segment. I'm also grabbing information from a database about each segment faces.

```
Segment 1 [Face1: Red, Face2: Green, Face3: Black ..... Face 36: Red]
.
.
Segment 20000 [...]
```

What would be the best way to render something like this where I have a lot of data going into it without a lot of performance issues?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indeed no simple matter. What I'd do myself is to probably disassemble THREE.Spline and change its logic to use BufferGeometry. So e.g. instead of creating a THREE.Vertice you'd add a position to the typed array. But that would probably take a while until you figured it out. Using a worker is not really a good idea because we have a memory issue here, not really a speed issue. And then you'd additionally have to pass the geometries between "threads".

Another approach is to build up your spline sequentially. So instead of

> Create THREE.Spline with thousands of vertices

you could

> Create THREE.Spline with 40 vertices which are around the camera. Display the inner 38 vertices. When camera moves create the following spline again with 40 vertices.

You'd have to have some camera logic like "where is my camera" and such. If you can do that computationally - perfect. If you don't know previously where your vertices are located or if there's no logic to their location then use a helper construct like http://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_nearestneighbour.

Comment: I have done the BufferGeometry part. What I'm probably thinking of doing is rendering the geometry at different resolutions the closer you go to it. If you are really close, it will render the stuff which is only on the camera in high resolution. If you are really far, it will render everything in low res. If you are inbetween, you get a more accurate geometry but not high res.

Comment: yeah that approach is called LOD = Level of Detail. That's a way to do it too. They do something similar here: http://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_lod But I fear you have to code whatever logic yourself. Good luck :)

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you check out the new BufferGeometry? I've managed to get a huge performance boost by doing so. Here's the docs entry to get you started: http://threejs.org/docs/#Reference/Core/BufferGeometry. Unfortunately, many examples are outdated, so beware. This one seems to work in r67, others don't: http://mrdoob.github.io/three.js/examples/#webgl_buffergeometry_rawshader.

Basically, you would preallocate a Float32Array of size 20000 * 36 * 3 * 3 (20000 segments * 36 faces * 3 vertices * 3 coordinates) and another one for colors. Then the arrays would be gradually filled with the data.

Comment: With the BufferGeometry, Wouldn't I have to know the position of each vertice? I am using the THREE.JS Spline to create a spline based on 80 different points. It seems like I'll have to know alot more information about the object.

Comment: @MohamadBataineh Guess you can extract the vertices from the Spline object using splineInstance.getPoint (just took a look at the docs).

Comment: The problem is that then I would have to create a spline with so many vertices/faces in the first place. Wouldn't that in itself be a hurdle or does the performance of BufferGeometry better even if I create the spline and not show it?

Comment: Well, in the first place, that should allow the scene to *render* just fine (we're talking 720000 faces here). Regarding the spline creation itself, you might want to try spawning a worker for it.